# Handling accent characters while sending EDI message to a destination in BizTalk Server

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, biztalk-orchestrations, custom-pipeline-component, biztalk-pipelines

I have a requirement in which I need to hardcode (is mandatory) a value ('A.H. La Kélisére') with accent characters, map this to a field in EDI schema and then send the message generated to a URI (dynamic send port) using AS2 transport. I have used the default pipeline 'AS2EdiSend' in the send port, but I am getting the below error:

There was a failure executing the send pipeline:……

```
Reason: Error: 1 (Segment level error)
    SegmentID: NAD
    Position in TS: 6
    21: Invalid character found

Error: 2 (Field level error)
    SegmentID: NAD
    Position in TS: 6
    Data Element ID: C05901
    Position in Segment: 6
    Position in Field: 1
    Data Value: A.H. La Kélisére
    21: Invalid character found
```

I need to send the value as it is. How can this be achieved?

Comment: What EDIFACT encoding are you using? https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2009/08/15/edifact-encoding-edi-character-set-support/

Comment: @Dijkgraaf: Thanks for your help. 
Previously I was using UNOA. I changed it to UNOB and tested it again. It still didn't work. Is there any specific encoding which I can use in this scenario?

Comment: UNOB does not support accented characters.  Read that article and select a character set that does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNOA & UNOB do not support accented charters.

Ask the recipient which [EDIFACT character set](https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2009/08/15/edifact-encoding-edi-character-set-support/) they support and change to that.

Comment: I changed that to UNOC and it worked. However, as you said I need to check if they support this character set.
Thanks for your help :)